# Laravel many to many with 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models

I've been struggling with a issue the last couple of days. I've just started using Laravel and are getting real fond of the Eloquent-syntax!
But there's a issue when I'm trying to get the correct relation between three models.

I've got this setup:

programs table contains

- event_id
- user_id
- role_id

In my Event-model I've got

```
public function programs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Program::class);
}
```

In my User-model I've got

```
public function programs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Program::class);
}
```

In my Role-model I've got

```
public function programs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Program::class);
}
```

And my Program-model contains

```
public function event(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

And I need to get the following result

```
Events -> Users -> Role
```

In my controller I've got
    $events = Event::with('programs.role.programs.user')->get();

Which is producing this:

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Concert: Freddy Kalas",
"description": "Freddy Kalas konsert",
"user_id": 2,
"time_from": "12.04.2017 22:00:00",
"time_to": "12.04.2017 23:00:00",
"created_at": "2017-03-20 18:28:44",
"updated_at": "2017-03-20 18:28:44",
"programs": [
  {
      "id": 2,
    "event_id": 2,
    "user_id": 2,
    "role_id": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "role": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Camera operator",
      "description": "Operates ordinary cameras or PTZ cameras",
      "created_at": "2017-03-20 20:11:06",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-20 20:11:06",
      "programs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
          "event_id": 3,
          "user_id": 2,
          "role_id": 1,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dummy Dum",
            "email": "dummy@example.com",
            "created_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09",
            "updated_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09"
          }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
          "event_id": 2,
          "user_id": 2,
          "role_id": 1,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dummy Dum",
            "email": "dummy@example.com",
            "created_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09",
            "updated_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
},
{
    "id": 3,
"name": "Prøveproduksjon",
"description": "Prøveproduksjon med video og lyd",
"user_id": 1,
"time_from": "11.04.2017 13:00:00",
"time_to": "11.04.2017 17:00:00",
"created_at": "2017-04-03 17:12:37",
"updated_at": "2017-04-03 17:12:37",
"programs": [
  {
      "id": 1,
    "event_id": 3,
    "user_id": 2,
    "role_id": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "role": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Camera operator",
      "description": "Operates ordinary cameras or PTZ cameras",
      "created_at": "2017-03-20 20:11:06",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-20 20:11:06",
      "programs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
          "event_id": 3,
          "user_id": 2,
          "role_id": 1,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dummy Dum",
            "email": "dummy@example.com",
            "created_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09",
            "updated_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09"
          }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
          "event_id": 2,
          "user_id": 2,
          "role_id": 1,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null,
          "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dummy Dum",
            "email": "dummy@example.com",
            "created_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09",
            "updated_at": "2017-03-20 16:45:09"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
}
```

I can't get the models to relate to eachother - it seems. The preferred result that I want is that all the Events is tied with many users - and all the users for that event to be tied to one role. How can i accomplish this with Laravel and Eloquent?

Thanks for any responses!

EDIT:
To fetch the data i use the following code to generate the results above

```
$events = Event::with('programs.role.programs.user')->get();
```

Content of the programs table

```
# id, event_id, user_id, role_id, created_at, updated_at
'1', '3', '2', '1', NULL, NULL
'2', '2', '2', '1', NULL, NULL
```

This would mean that the user with an ID of 2 is only associated with event 3 with an role of 1 and event 2 with a role of 1. As you can see from the results both events has both role 1 and 2. Sorry for bad explanation..

Comment: Your relations looks good. It's probably just the way your trying to get the data that is not good. Can you post the part that is not working in your code?

Comment: Sorry @ettdro - should have included that in the original post. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Isn't that what you got there?? I'm not sure to really understand what you want? If we look to what your `$event` returns, you have an Event with 2 users and a role associated to them.

Comment: @ettdro I've included the contents of the programs-table - so it might be clearer what results I want.

Comment: Probably just try to make it one at a time and figure out what is returned?

Comment: You absolutly led me down the right path @ettdro! Got it working now by using _$events = Event::with('programs.role')->with('programs.user')->get();_ It seems kind of dirty.. but it works :) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem sir! Just remember if something similar happens in the future... just break it down! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably just try to make it one at a time and figure out what is returned.

@Fredrik Angell Moe said:

Got it working now by using:

`$events = Event::with('programs.role')->with('programs.user')->get();`

Comment: Do you realise you can do this: `$events = Event::with('programs.role', 'programs.user')->get();`

Comment: @Fredrik Angell Moe check this out for cleaner code!

Answer (score 0):

> user with an ID of 2 is only associated with event 3 with an role of 1
>   and event 2 with a role of 1. As you can see from the results both
>   events has both role 1 and 2.

You are using two values. One is id of user and second is id of event.

Laravel can define realtion between only two models. That means in you query you are using the programe_id and event_id.

But user_id is getting neglected. So it will just add the user related to the model instead of filtering with the user_id.

The best way to solve this problem is instead of using the relation go for the raw query where you need to get relation between more than two models.